# How to save tweet information into ordered JSON using Tweepy Cursor api.search?

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I want to save tweet information in JSON format like this :

```
{
    "created_at":
    "id":
    "id_str":
    "text":
.
.
.
etc
```

[UPDATED] it works with this code. Yay! it's finally save all tweet information. But there's another problem, it's unordered, i want the order like above, not alphabetical order

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import tweepy
import time

ckey ='x'
csecret = 'x'
atoken = 'x'
asecret ='x'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,geocode="-   6.1750,106.8283,438.37km",since='2016-02-18',until='2016-02-24').items():
    with open('dataJakarta2.json', 'a') as f:
        for abc in tweet.entities.get("urls",[{}]):
            if "swarmapp.com" not in abc.get("expanded_url",None):
                continue
            else:
               f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
               f.write("\n")
```